# Meteor.js: Error while applying changes: Error: There is already a collection named ____

Tags: javascript, meteor

Whenever I save a server side file in my api directory, this error appears as soon as the auto refresh happens. After looking through similar questions on SO, it seems that this error is supposed to appear when said collection is getting imported more than once.

The issue I'm having is that not only are there no duplicate collection imports, this error only appears on the auto-reload (whenever I save the file). So when I start the application and am using it regularly, there is no sign of this error--indicating that this may be a development issue.

Here is what my folder structure looks like:

/imports/api/books.js

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';

export const Books = new Mongo.Collection("books");
```

/server/main.js

```
import "../imports/api/books.js";
```

So in this case, the full error is:

```
HMR: Error while applying changes: Error: There is already a collection named "books"
    at Collection._maybeSetUpReplication (collection.js:314:15)
    at new Collection (collection.js:121:8)
    at eval (books.js:5:22)
    at module (books.js:713:1)
    at hot-module-replacement.js?hash=8bbefadb77097ac852d6d5dd3db9f23e39ee3511:415:7
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime-hot.js?hash=325e29e1f9abcee55f3cef85ec8a56670bbc6194:388:7)
    at Module.require (modules-runtime-hot.js?hash=325e29e1f9abcee55f3cef85ec8a56670bbc6194:270:27)
    at require (modules-runtime-hot.js?hash=325e29e1f9abcee55f3cef85ec8a56670bbc6194:310:21)
    at hot-module-replacement.js?hash=8bbefadb77097ac852d6d5dd3db9f23e39ee3511:602:7
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

I am currently using Meteor version 2.9.0.

Comment: This error happens when you declare `new Mongo.Collection("books")` twice. Review your code to check if `books.js` is imported more than one time or if you have this code already in another place.

Comment: @RicardoAragão As mentioned in my question, I do not have any double imports. However, I have since received confirmation from the Meteor team that this is a known bug. Posted details in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received confirmation [from the Meteor team](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/12404) that this is actually a known bug and they offered me a hotfix solution in the meantime (which I can confirm resolves the issue).

> This happens when a module that creates a collection is re-run by HMR
>
> - each time the module is re-run, it creates a new instance of the collection. HMR is only used on the client, so the file is imported on
>   the client some place.
>
> Until this bug is fixed, a workaround is to add this to the file to
> prevent HMR from re-running the file. Instead, it will use hot code
> push and reload the page.

```
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.decline();
}
```